# Multi-conditions data filtering involving BOOLEAN columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am lost in trying to filter data from a table containing `BOOLEAN` columns, where the filtering conditions apply some further consideration on one of the `BOOLEAN` columns.

I explain my question with example below, reproduced in this [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aO6i3pSg).

```sql
CREATE TABLE trip_segments(trip_id INT,segment_id INT,trip_timestamp TIMESTAMP, 
  trip_distance DOUBLE PRECISION,  foot BOOLEAN,bike BOOLEAN, bus BOOLEAN, car BOOLEAN)

INSERT INTO trip_segments(trip_id, segment_id, trip_timestamp, trip_distance,
  foot, bike, bus, car)
VALUES  (535521,2,'2016-04-08 13:56:41+01',9008.23,false,false,false,true),
 (536625,8,'2016-04-11 17:38:02+01',9821.37,true,false,false,false),
 (536624,1,'2016-04-11 14:23:20+01',1872.41,true,false,false,false),
 (537733,3,'2016-04-13 13:19:49+01',14967.96,true,false,true,false),
 (536623,0,'2016-04-11 10:08:32+01',8244.27,false,false,true,false), 
 (544627,5,'2016-04-25 11:24:37+01',3648.63,false,true,false,false)
```

So in this table, I want retrieve rows that satisfy the following conditions:

- rows in which ONLY one of `foot, bike, bus` or `car` is **TRUE**.
- further, `foot` trips should only be selected if `trip_distance < 5000` (foot trip over `5,000m` is deviant).
- trips covered between `2016-4-07` and `2106-4-15` only.

My query below didn't return expected result:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM trip_segments
WHERE foot 
  AND trip_distance < 5000
AND trip_timestamp BETWEEN '2016-04-07' AND '2016-04-15'

trip_id segment_id  trip_timestamp    trip_distance foot    bike    bus car
536624      1      2016-04-11 14:23:20  1872.41      t        f      f   f
```

Expected output:

```sql
trip_id segment_id    trip_timestamp    trip_distance   foot    bike    bus car
535521      2      2016-04-08 13:56:41     9008.23        f       f      f   t
536624      1      2016-04-11 14:23:20     1872.41        t       f      f   f
536623      0      2016-04-11 10:08:32     8244.27        f       f      t   f
```

Here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aO6i3pSg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition can be written as:

```
SELECT *
FROM trip_segments
WHERE (
   (foot and not bike and not bus and not car AND trip_distance < 5000)
   OR (not foot and bike and not bus and not car)
   OR (not foot and not bike and bus and not car)
   OR (not foot and not bike and not bus and car)
  )
AND trip_timestamp BETWEEN '2016-04-07' AND '2016-04-15'
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bCGAZyKR).

Comment: But this includes trip on `2016-04-25` which is out of date range.

Comment: @arilwan My bad. See fixed query.

Answer (score 1):

Add an additional `WHERE` condition:

```
AND foot::integer + bus::integer + bike::integer + car::integer = 1
```

Comment: Returns the same result despite adding this.

Comment: Then I must have  misunderstood your question. I thought you want all these conditions `AND`ed.